# Array Of Number And Finding SubArray

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input = **5 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 8 7 6**

In This Input, The longest subarray is [6, 10] where maximum=8 and minimum are 7 and difference is 1. Difference Should be Less And Equal To 1.

a subarray such that the difference between the minimum and the maximum value in that range is at most 1

Output Should Be 7 8 8 8 7
Please Suggest Me How To Code?

```
#THIS IS MY CODE
n = int(input())
data = []

for _ in range(n):
    data.append(int(input()))

for i in range(0,n):
    maxi = max(data[i+1:])
    mini = min(data[i+1:])
    diff = maxi - mini

    if diff <= 1:
       print(data[i:])
       l = len(data[i:])
       print(l)
       break
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what a `subarray` exactly is?

Comment: a subarray such that the difference between the minimum and the maximum value in that range is at most 1

Comment: Naive approach would be to start building subarrays from [0] to end of list, and remember the biggest one you got. Repeat from [1] and keep only "better" subarrays. Repeat until you hit end of list with a subarray. Print your "best" subarray.

Comment: I Didn't Understand

Comment: Start from the left side and build a subarray, and save it. Remove the first item from input, and build a subarray again from left side. If it is bigger than the one you already have saved, save the new one, else keep the old one. Repeat until you hit the right side of input, or your input list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive solution. Make every possible sub-list and filter out those that meet your condition.

```
import numpy as np
a = [5,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,7,6]
max_diff = 1
sub_arrays = [x for x in [a[i:j] for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(i+1, len(a))] if (max(x)-min(x) <= max_diff)]
max_sub_array = sub_arrays[np.argmax([len(sa) for sa in sub_arrays])]
```

On your sample input, the output is:

```
[7, 8, 8, 8, 7]
```